# What does mean the vertical bars in the chrome perfomance tab

Tags: performance, google-chrome, load, paint

[image: chrome performance tab]

Blue probably means the documentload, and the red the load, but the other ones probably refer to first time painting among other related performance events.

Does anyone knows?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Was wondering the same.. also found that information, but still no clue about the 'yellow' ones..